# Search criteria and NULL

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have been using the following method pattern in my Web API for searching entities given a set of criteria:

```
public IEnumerable<Employee> Search(SearchCriteria searchCriteria)
{
    var employees = _dbContext.Employees;

    if(searchCriteria.Age.HasValue)
    {
        employees = employees.Where(e => e.Age == searchCriteria.Age.Value);
    }

    if(searchCriteria...)
    {
        employees = employees.Where(e => ...);
    }

    return employees;
}
```

If a search criterion is not specified, then the property on the SearchCriteria object will be `null` and I simply do not filter based on this criterion. If it is specified, then it will have a value, and it is used for filtering.

The problem, from a design perspective, is that if I actually want the `employees` that do not have an age, I simply cannot do it this way, since I use `null` to determine whether or not I will use the given criterion.

What other approach should I look into in order to emcompass both cases?

Perhaps looking at the URI instead of letting Web API do the object mapping, I could determine whether or not the criterion was actually present?

```
mysite.com/api/employee?keyword=a&age=null
```

vs

```
mysite.com/api/employee?keyword=a
```

Comment: Couldn't you use `if(searchCriteria.Age.HasValue)` ... `else {}` if you're looking for employees with null `Age`s?

Comment: What value do the employees have when they have no age?

Comment: @TravisJ: In the database, that would be NULL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll have to extend your `SearchCriteria` a bit. Instead of `Nullable<T>` properties like `Nullable<int> Age` you'll need a more detailed structure, that gives you the info, if that criterion should be checked or not.

This might additionally give you the option to not just combine your criterions with logical ANDs but also tweak some more functionality out of it ;)

Answer (score 0):

For the filtering the age, maybe you can set the age to -1, for querying employees that do not have an age like:

```
    if(searchCriteria.Age.HasValue){
        if(searchCriteria.Age != -1)
            employees = employees.Where(e => e.Age == searchCriteria.Age.Value);
        }
        else{
            employees = employees.Where(e => e.Age == null);
    }
}
```

Comment: @TravisJ: This solution means that for every case, you need some arbitrary value that means "no value" that isn't null. In the case of int, it can be -1 for the age of a person.

Comment: Setting "invalid" criterions to some magic numbers like -1 seems quite dirty to me.

Comment: Actually it is a little bit dirty if you do not validate the user input for the age, but I think it is perfectly applicable if you check the age boundaries of employees or if user entered a negative value for the age. Then you can set the age to -1 in case you want to search for employees that don't have age value

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use a conditional check here. If the database value of age can be null, then that means your domain entity must be `int?` in which case `Age` can be used without `.Value`.

```
public IEnumerable<Employee> Search(SearchCriteria searchCriteria)
{
  var employees = _dbContext.Employees.Where(e => e.Age == searchCriteria.Age);

  if(searchCriteria...)
  {
    employees = employees.Where(e => ...);
  }

  return employees;
}
```

Comment: What do you do in the case where you want to search but not based on age, i.e., if the the age criterion is optional?

Comment: @GabrielG.Roy - If age is optional, then that sounds like you may want SearchCriteria to include some sort of flag `bool UseAge` or something similar that you can check in this method.

Comment: @GabrielG.Roy - Alternatively, you could overload the method to accept a subset of SearchCriteria.